# Naming Convention for Entity Models when Using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, naming-conventions

When I am using Entity Code First to create my database, what naming convention should I use if I am creating a MVC 4 Project in asp.net. I want to make it clear that the Entity Models arent MVC models. For example should I have a class called `Project` that defines the properties that EF will use, and then create a MVC model called `ProjectModel`. I will also have viewModels, which will be somehwhat different then the Models that would be in the form of `ProjectDashboardViewModel. What are the recommendations for naming conventions when setting up a project like this?

Comment: What is an "MVC Model?"  The "M" in Model-View-Controller refers to your application domain and business logic.  It includes your database and the EF classes that represent your entities.  Is that what you are referring to when you say "MVC Model?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well I dont pass my EF models directly to views, so they are technically different then the models that MVC uses. I have three types of models in my Project Entity (these create EF database stuff), MVC Models (This just abstracts the EF Class), and ViewModels (this actually provides the view the data it needs). Is this not a correct approach to take?

Comment: It sounds like you're referring to either a repository or a service layer.  What is the purpose of providing an additional layer of indirection with your "MVC models?"  EF already provides a layer of indirection with its Entity Classes.  Couldn't your app just use the EF classes directly, or through a thin repository layer?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well my understanding was that I shouldn't ever pass my entity models directly to views. Our repo layer contains only what is needed to create the EF stuff. But because it some of our view models we use two or three classes that are passed in as objects we create these other classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have strong naming conventions expressed in question. I do use exactly same ones :)

1. No prefixing for domain models - `Project`
2. `Model` suffix for mvc classes that are not quite view models - `ProjectTableRowModel`
3. `ViewModel` suffix for view models - `ProjectDetailsViewModel`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a question like this can have many answers, there isn't really a defacto standard but here's what I do.

First off I create an empty solution, let's called it **MyProject**. Then I add a class library to this solution called **MyProject** (I like to have the domain at the root namespace). This class library will contain certain folders / namespaces like so:

```
MyProject
    Entities
        MyEntity1.cs
        MyEntity2.cs
    Database
        MyContext.cs
```

Then I add an MVC project to my solution, calling it **MyProject.Mvc**. I use `ViewModels` and `DataTransferObjects` within **MyProject.Mvc** and use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to construct them using my entities. I have a `ViewModel` for every view, so say I have a controller called `DashboardController` with an action called `Overview`  then I'll have a `DashboardOverviewViewModel` object specifically for that.

One benefit of having my domain separate is that it becomes easier to unit test, where I'll have corresponding test projects called **MyProject.Tests** and **MyProject.Mvc.Tests**.

[This article is very helpful as another perspective for ViewModel handling](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to place your entities that will map to database tables into a separate class library in the solution.

Your suggestion of using Project for the DB model and ProjectModel for the MVC model is appropriate.

I would argue that your ProjectModel is actually a ProjectViewModel, since the choice of properties and how they are populated is driven primarily by the presentation requirements.  Just because you may not have a Project View, doesn't mean you can't have a Project ViewModel.  Perhaps your ProjectDashboardViewModel contains many ProjectViewModel objects.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about better readability and maintainability.

You could create a library for ViewModels, say SomeProduct.ViewModel.dll and refer this in MVC web project. Suffix classes in this assembly with "ViewModel", say RevenueViewModel/RegisterViewModel. Also create namespace inside this project to organize view models module wise.

And for entities you could create another library, say SomeProduct.Entities.dll and refer this assembly in MVC web project. Again effectively use namespace to organize objects within the assembly. You could suffix these objects with "Model".